# Obtaining a upper frame bound for the dual Riesz basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a Riesz basis with bounds $A$ and $B,$ and $\{ g_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be its dual Riesz basis. Show that 
$$\frac{1}{B} \leq \| g_k \| \leq \frac{1}{A}.$$

Note that $|<f_k,g_i>|=\delta_{k,i},$ where $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{ g_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ are biorthogonal systems. Then we have
$$1=|\langle  f_k , g_k \rangle | \leq \| f_k \| \cdot \| g_k \| \leq B \cdot \| g_k \|,$$
which implies 
$$\| g_k \| \geq \frac{1}{B}.$$

I'm stuck in obtaining a corresponding upper bound. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that your inequalies should be
$$\frac{1}{B} \leq \| g_k \|^2 \leq \frac{1}{A},$$
i.e., the norm should be squared.

For the upper bound, suppose the system $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Riesz basis with corresponding biorthogonal system $\{ g_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then [1, Proposistion 3.7.3] implies that the system $\{g_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Bessel sequence with bound $A^{-1}$, i.e., for all $f \in \mathcal{H}$, it holds that
$$ \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} | \langle f, g_k \rangle |^2 \leq \frac{1}{A} \|f \|_{\mathcal{H}}^2. $$
Take $g_j \in \{g_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $g_j \in \mathcal{H}$, and
$$ \| g_j \|_{\mathcal{H}}^4 =  |\langle g_j , g_j \rangle|^2 \leq  \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} | \langle g_j, g_k \rangle |^2 \leq \frac{1}{A} \|g_j \|_{\mathcal{H}}^2, $$
which yields the result.

[1] Christensen, O. *An Introduction to Riesz Bases and Frames (second edition)*. Birkhauser, 2016.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Sadly the norm in "not-squared." I've added a picture from the same book, page 119.

Comment: @ManMath. Thanks for uploading the figure. However, the norm should really be squared. It seems to be a typo in the first edition of the book. I just checked it in the second edition of 2016. Please see Exercise 5.9 of this new edition.

Comment: thank you. Do you know whether there's an errata available ?

Comment: @ManMath. I do not think there is an errata available. However, I know from experience that typos and errors are very rare in this book.